# Trying to get an active email Message ID

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I've been reading a lot to find a response by myself before I post here, but I don't know what I'm missing, I'm trying to match the email message ID with a value in Google's spreadsheet, I have this 2 functions :

```
function getExpenseDescription(message) { 
  var id = message.getId();
  return id;
}

function getReceivedDate(message){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  // seleccionamos el id de la tabla que se desea utilizar
  var ss = app.openById("google sheet id");
  // seleccionamos la hoja con la que deseamos trabajar
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Respuestas de formulario 1");
  // seleccionamos todos los datos de la tabla 
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
// var id = "1620cc3997025bf5";
  var id = message.getId();
  Logger.log(id);
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length;i++){
    if(data[i][73] == id){ 
      Logger.log((i+1))
      return id = i+1;
    }
  }
```

the first function returns the message ID, but when I use the same message.getId() in the second saids that can't getId of undefined

here's the other code where you get the token to access gmail

```
function getContextualAddOn(event) {
  var message = getCurrentMessage(event);
  var prefills = [getReceivedDate(message),
                  getLargestAmount(message),
                  getExpenseDescription(message),
                  getSheetUrl()];
  var card = createExpensesCard(prefills);

  return [card.build()];
}

/**
 * Retrieves the current message given an action event object.
 * @param {Event} event Action event object
 * @return {Message}
 */
function getCurrentMessage(event) {
  var accessToken = event.messageMetadata.accessToken;
  var messageId = event.messageMetadata.messageId;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
  return GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
}
```

Comment: `getExpenseDescription` and `getReceivedDate` are getting called at the same place and the same object is passed as a parameter. It doesn't make sense that `message.getId()` works in one and not in other. Could you double-check that? Also, this might not solve the issue, but `messageMetadata.messageId` [is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/event-objects#event_object_structure). You should be using `gmail.messageId` instead.

Comment: I checked more than twice, that's why I'm going crazy trying to figure out what's going on, I'm not a cod expert, but I'm trying to find another way to get this to work

Comment: Do you have 74 columns?

Comment: hi cooper yes, on the spreadsheet

Comment: @alfonsopeñaranda That's very strange. Could you share a copy of the file you're working on, so that this behaviour can be reproduced?